# How to set different depth limits for different websites when crawling in python scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

My current program is

```
class DNCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    urls = []
    url = ""

    def __init__(self):
```

#I am populating urls here from databse

```
     self.urls = {'link':'http://www.amcastle.com', 'depth_limit':1}, {'link':'http://192.168.7.54/crawl_test.php', 'depth_limit':2}
     self.url = self.get_next_url()

   def start_requests(self):
```

#yielding request using generator
        link = self.url.next()
        while(link.link != ''):
 #trying override the depth limit

```
      settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = link.depth_limit
      yield Request(link, callback=self.crawl_recursive)
      link = self.url.next()
```

But the depth_limit is not working per site. But when crawling it is considering  depth_limit provided in setting page. Is there any way to deal with depth_limit in program. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `meta` attribute of the `Request` object to track the present depth and maximum depth:

```
yield Request(link.link, callback=self.crawl_recursive, meta={'present_depth': 0, 'depth_limit': link.depth_limit})
```

Then, your parsing method can check the depth like so:

```
def crawl_recursive(self, response):
    if response.meta["present_depth"] > response.meta["depth_limit"]:
        #too deep!
        return []
```

Remember to increment the present_depth when you create new `Request`s and you'll be set.